# API Platform - how to document authentication routes

Tags: symfony, swagger, openapi, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform v2.2.5 in a Symfony 4 Flex application, consisting of a functioning API with [JWT Authentication](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/#jwt-authentication), a number of resources and the default [Open API/Swagger documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger) page that is accessible via the `/api` route. Each API resource is included in the documentation automatically via the platform configuration, as per the [library docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/getting-started#mapping-the-entities).

How do you generate documentation for custom operations such as the security component's auth routes? The [API Platform Documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger) does not seem to include these instructions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to [this comment in a Github issue](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues/143#issuecomment-260221717). Since I am using YAML for resource configuration I had to translate, the example for the auth/login endpoint;

```
App\Entity\User:
  collectionOperations:
  auth:
    route_name: auth
    swagger_context:
      parameters:
        -
          name: username
          required: true
          type: string
          description: "User's username or email address"

        -
          name: password
          required: true
          type: string
          description: "User's password"

      responses:
        200:
          description: "Successful login attempt, returning a new token"
          schema:
            type: object
            required:
              - username
              - password
            properties:
              username:
                type: string

              password:
                type: string

      summary: Performs a login attempt, returning a valid token on success
      consumes:
        - "application/json"
        - "application/ld-json"
      produces:
        - "application/ld-json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: its openapi_contex instead of swagger_contex for openapi/swagger v3.