# Adding auth route to generate a JWT in OpenApi 3

Tags: swagger, symfony4, openapi, api-platform.com

I would like to achieve this kind of result with ApiPlatform and OpenApi V3:
[image: screen shot of an old swagger displaying an auth route]

I found this on an old SO question : [How to add Login to swagger UI with API PLATFORM (symfony 4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380730/how-to-add-login-to-swagger-ui-with-api-platform-symfony-4)

The route is plugged onto a LexikJWT handler in my firewalls, from security.yaml.

I managed to add a custom thing in the ItemOperations key of my resources.yaml but the thing doesn't seem to map properly to OpenApi.

Am I understanding something wrongly?

Should I drop Lexik JWT bundle and do the auth in an other way?

Am I missing something around schemes or YAML configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May help if you use [Nelmio Api Doc Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html) with Symfony

I end up with definition of the **endpoint** by manual update of `config/packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml`

The final version looked as follows

```
config/packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml
nelmio_api_doc:
    models:
        use_jms: false
    documentation:
        info:
            title: My fancy API
            description: Documentation
            version: 1.0.0
        components:
            securitySchemes:
                Bearer:
                    type: http
                    scheme: bearer
                    bearerFormat: JWT
        security:
            - Bearer: []
  
# Begin of manual endpoint definition  
#####################################

        paths:
          /api/auth/login:
            post:
              tags:
                - Login
              description: Login into the api.
              requestBody:
                description: Json body
                required: true
                content:
                  application/json:
                    schema:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        username:
                          type: string
                        password:
                          type: string
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Login successful
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                          token:
                            type: string
                          refresh_token:
                            type: string
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have problem with `config/routes.yaml` file. My config looking like:

```
api_login_check:
  path: /api/users/login
  methods: [POST]
```

For you may be need put as `path: /authentication`

Just in case, I am write here the full JWT configuration of my project.

**config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml:**

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    user_identity_field: phone <-- for auth user (username/login)
    token_ttl: 3600
```

**config/packages/security.yaml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: phone <-- it's my property that i use as username

    firewalls:

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
            json_login:
                check_path: ~
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
```

**src/Entity/User.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

// use ...

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     security="is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get" = {"security" = "is_granted('ROLE_USER') and object == user"},
 *         // other operations ...
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "post" = {
 *             "security" = "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')"
 *         },
 *         "login" = {
 *             "security" = "is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')",
 *             "route_name" = "api_login_check",
 *             "method" = "POST",
 *             "openapi_context" = {
 *                 "summary" = "Login method",
 *                 "requestBody" = {
 *                     "description" = "Get token",
 *                     "content" = {
 *                         "application/json" = {
 *                             "schema" = {
 *                                 "type" = "object",
 *                                 "required" = {
 *                                     "username",
 *                                     "password"
 *                                 },
 *                                 "properties" = {
 *                                     "username" = {
 *                                         "type" = "string"
 *                                     },
 *                                     "password" = {
 *                                         "type" = "string"
 *                                     }
 *                                 }
 *                             }
 *                         }
 *                     }
 *                 }
 *             }
 *         },
 *         // other operations ...
 *     },
 *     // ...
 * )
 * // ...
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

P.S. I am using Symfony V5, but I think it is no different

Answer (score 0):

I found out the docs have been updated, the solution was to check the swagger decorator side.
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/

Comment: lol) if I understand you correctly. No problem, use the decorator to change only url :D